# Failing with shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to run the following script in Ubuntu 10.04 but hitting with different issues for the intget i declaration. Could anyone please help me asap

```bsh
integer i

i=1

while true
    do
    read response

    if [ -z == $response ] 
    then
     continue 
    fi

    if [ $response == "q" ]
    then
     break
    fi


    if [ -f /var/tmp/UE1_${i}.txt ]
    then
      cat /var/tmp/UE1_${i}.txt
      i=$i+1
    fi


    if [ $i -eq  100 ] 
    then
     break
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
integer i
i=1
```

Simple `i=1` without spaces is enough.

```bsh
if [ -z == $response ] 
    then
        continue 
fi
```

`continue` means skip everything in the loop that comes after `continue` and goto next iteration of loop. I don't think that's what you intended to do.

```bsh
if [ $response == "q" ]
```

It's a best practice to enclose variable names in double quotes (`"$response"`) when referencing.

```bsh
i=$i+1
```

This will assign `1+1` as a string to `$i` instead on `2`. You can either use
`expr`:

```bsh
i=$(expr $i + 1)
```

or simply use:

```bsh
(( i++ ))
```

Your final script will look somthing like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

i=1

while true
do
    read response

    if [ "$response" == "q" ]
    then
        break
    fi

    if [ -f /var/tmp/UE1_${i}.txt ]
    then
        cat /var/tmp/UE1_${i}.txt
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    fi

    if [ $i -eq  100 ] 
    then
        break
    fi

done
```

For more info on bash scripting checkout this excellent tutorial: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In bash you dont have to declare types as in other languages such as in C family.

So the first line `integer i` causes erros in its form. You can just remove it.

There is a case where you can tell bash that the declared variable must be treated as of *some type*, this can be done if you edit the first line to:
`declare (option) variable=value` in your case:
`declare -r i=1` the `-r` option tells bash that the variable must be treated as an integer.

You can check the available options for variable declarations [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_01.html).